# How to know that a text box is being edited?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, windows-7, operating-system

There is an onscreen keyboard application called Hot Virtual Keyboard available at http://hot-virtual-keyboard.com/. In this keyboard there is a check box in settings:

```
    [x] Show the on-screen keyboard when the text cursor is visible
```

When this check box is checked, keyboard automatically gets visible whenever a text box is being edited either it is in Adobe Reader or it is simple notpad application.
I want to know how it is done in C#, is this event (editing in textBox) broadcasted in whole system and Hot Virtual Keyboard receives it or is this something else.

Please let me know how can I listen to such events in Windows 7.

Thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be you will need to implement hooking at windows level. For more on hooking refer to this [Post](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying to find a dll/function set somewhere in the Windows API.. You will probably need to call out to native dlls. You could start by finding when the cursor changes to the edit icon, and activating your virtual keyboard there.

Another thing you could try is listening to windows messages via the Control.WndProc method.